# Magento2-Send email notification to main admin when price changed by admin

Tags: magento2.3, price, adminnotification

I want to send eamil notification to main admin, for modification avail in price by any admin.

Please help,

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the **around** plugin for your requirement. **around** plugin should be used on *afterSave($object)* method of **\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price** class.

This class has been assigned as *backend_model* to product prices attributes so when product prices will be updated this *backend_model* class will be called.

So below given code will be useful to you to send the email when value of **price** attribute will be changed.

**FILE: Kartik\PriceUpdate\etc\adminhtml\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price">
        <plugin name="send_email_when_price_change" type="Kartik\PriceUpdate\Plugin\Product\Attribute\Backend\PricePlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**FILE: Kartik\PriceUpdate\Plugin\Product\Attribute\Backend\PricePlugin.php**

```
<?php
namespace Kartik\PriceUpdate\Plugin\Product\Attribute\Backend;

class PricePlugin
{
    const PRICE_ATTRIBUTE = 'price';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param $object
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function aroundAfterSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price $subject, callable $proceed, $object)
    {
        $result = $proceed($object);
        $attributeCode = $subject->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();

        if ($attributeCode == self::PRICE_ATTRIBUTE) {
            if ($object->hasData($attributeCode)) {
                $originalData = $object->getOrigData($attributeCode);
                $newData = $object->getData($attributeCode);

                if ($originalData !== $newData) {
                    // implement your email logic here
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Plugin is always better option while implementing this type of requirement. If plugin is not helpful then only you should move to different solution.

Comment: Thank you, this is work properly and usefull thing.

Comment: Great. You can vote for the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to hook in to the `catalog_product_save_after` event to create an observer, & look at `$observer->getProduct()->getData()` to see the new data. You can compare a specific number of fields (eg: `price`, `special_price`) by checking `getData()` vs `getOrigData()`

[There's a more complete answer here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/201024/81375) which should hold up for Magento 2.3.

Comment: Thank you, This is also work properly.